# how to apply css to a specific element of a table?

Tags: css

I have a table like below

[image]

Consider the table id="testtable", and there is no class or id to uniquely identify the 
specific td shown in the above screen.

I found a way to access second tr in this example like below

[image]

but i got stuck with accessing the second td in this second tr.

Anyone could you please give me a hand on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe this help you dude :)

```
#testtable tbody > tr:first-child+tr > td:firt-child+td
{
}
```

or you can use the :nth-child pseudo class like this:

```
#testtable > tr:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(2)
{

}
```

**Note** though, this won't work in older browsers (or IE), you'll need to give the cells a class or use javascript in that case.

Comment: I change my answer ,look at it again

Answer (score 0):

you may use :nth-child()

http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/

```
#testtable tbody >:tr:nth-child(2)
{

}
```